# Searchkick with aws elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, searchkick

Im having a problem with searchkick and elasticsearch and using the faraday_middleware-aws-signers-v4 gem.  If I leave my elasticsearch.rb initializer blank, it works on my development side.  However if I put in the configuration for AWS Elasticsearch I get a json parse error.  Here is my elasticsearch.rb file:

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

Searchkick.aws_credentials = {
  access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
  secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
  region: "us-west-2"
}
```

I followed the instructions on the github page for AWS.  I left out the ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] because that is defined in my env files.  I tried it with it in there and it gave the same results.  Ive also tried it this way, which was the old way it was suppose to have it and get same results:

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

Searchkick.client =
  Elasticsearch::Client.new(
    url: ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'],
    transport_options: {request: {timeout: 10}}
  ) do |f|
    f.request :aws_signers_v4, {
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
      service_name: "es",
      region: "us-west-2"
    }
  end
```

Ive been able to narrow it down to this configuration though.

Edit: Heres the full error output:

```
livingrecipe_1   | Oj::ParseError - unexpected character at line 1, column 1 [parse.c:690]:
livingrecipe_1   |   multi_json (1.12.2) lib/multi_json/adapters/oj.rb:15:in `load'
livingrecipe_1   |   multi_json (1.12.2) lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:21:in `load'
livingrecipe_1   |   multi_json (1.12.2) lib/multi_json.rb:122:in `load'
livingrecipe_1   |   elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/serializer/multi_json.rb:24:in `load'
livingrecipe_1   |   elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:322:in `perform_request'
livingrecipe_1   |   elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
livingrecipe_1   |   elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:131:in `perform_request'
livingrecipe_1   |   elasticsearch-api (5.0.4) lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/info.rb:15:in `info'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick.rb:77:in `server_version'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick.rb:81:in `server_below?'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/query.rb:906:in `below50?'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/query.rb:723:in `set_order'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/query.rb:437:in `prepare'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/query.rb:43:in `initialize'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick.rb:95:in `search'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/model.rb:29:in `searchkick_search'
livingrecipe_1   |   app/helpers/recipe_search.rb:18:in `search'
livingrecipe_1   |   app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:9:in `index'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   searchkick (2.3.1) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   activerecord (5.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionview (5.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in serve'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:189:in `call!'
livingrecipe_1   |   omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:167:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:189:in `call!'
livingrecipe_1   |   omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:167:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   omniauth (1.6.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   clearance (1.16.0) lib/clearance/rack_session.rb:23:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   activerecord (5.1.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
livingrecipe_1   |   better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
livingrecipe_1   |   better_errors (2.3.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
livingrecipe_1   |   web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
livingrecipe_1   |   web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
livingrecipe_1   |   railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
livingrecipe_1   |   railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:122:in `block in call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack-timeout (0.4.2) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:121:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
livingrecipe_1   |   puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
livingrecipe_1   |   puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
livingrecipe_1   |   puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
livingrecipe_1   |   puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Highly possible that your env is not setup correctly and `ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']` is blank. Can you check this value by puts/Rails.logger ?

Comment: So when I look at the variables in the console they print out correctly.  Also would be very surprised if it was them cause I havent touched my .env file in a long time and this just started happening.  But to make sure I took out the env variables and hard coded in the values to test and got the same error

Comment: So searchkick guys got back to me on their github page and the error was I needed to include faraday_middleware gem and set the gzip.  See the issue here https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/982

Comment: This is interesting. Ideally, the server *does not* send gzipped response until the client advertises that it accepts gzip in header. Does this mean that Searchkick client is doing that by default and not caring about accepting the gzipped response?

Comment: Im not sure, but I let them know about the issue on their page, so hopefully they address it or at least mention in the readme to include that gem as a dependency

Comment: Sure. thanks. I commented on the issue with the question as well :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might stumble upon this and need the answer.  This had to do with the way Elasticsearch 5 returns the request in a gzip compressed format.  By using the faraday_middleware gem and setting it in the initializer like so:

```
require 'faraday/middleware'
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

Searchkick.client =
  Elasticsearch::Client.new(
    url: ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"],
    transport_options: {request: {timeout: 10}}
  ) do |f|
    f.use FaradayMiddleware::Gzip
    f.request :aws_signers_v4, {
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]),
      service_name: "es",
      region: "us-west-2"
    }
  end
```

It was able to handle the return request perfectly.  See comments above for reference to post on the searchkick github page